# how to export the Scraped data into excel with pre-defined header python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

currently i am printing the data.now rather than printing i want to export to

excel./csv new to python pls help.

**data is very huge around 9000 rows with 6 columns?**

```
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def scrape_bid_data():

page_no = 1 #initial page number
while True:
    print('Hold on creating URL to fetch data...')
    URL = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' + str(page_no) #create dynamic URL
    print('URL cerated: ' + URL)

    scraped_data = requests.get(URL,verify=False) # request to get the data
    soup_data = bs(scraped_data.text, 'lxml') #parse the scraped data using lxml
    extracted_data = soup_data.find('div',{'id':'pagi_content'}) #find divs which contains required data

    if len(extracted_data) == 0: # **if block** which will check the length of extracted_data if it is 0 then quit and stop the further execution of script.
        break
    else:
        for idx in range(len(extracted_data)): # loops through all the divs and extract and print data
            if(idx % 2 == 1): #get data from odd indexes only because we have required data on odd indexes
                bid_data = extracted_data.contents[idx].text.strip().split('\n')
                print('-' * 100)
                print(bid_data[0]) #BID number
                print(bid_data[5]) #Items
                print(bid_data[6]) #Quantitiy Required
                print(bid_data[10] + bid_data[12].strip()) #Department name and address
                print(bid_data[16]) #Start date
                print(bid_data[17]) #End date                   
                print('-' * 100)

        page_no +=1 #increments the page number by 1

 scrape_bid_data()
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! This question is too open. Can you state what approaches you tried so far and why they did not work or where you got stuck?

Comment: @blami i think he struck on exporting data to excel

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by returning the extract_data object containing your data at the end of your function.

```
 page_no = 1
 def scrap_bid_data(page):

     print('Hold on creating URL to fetch data...')
     URL = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' + str(page)
     print('URL cerated: ' + URL)

     scraped_data = requests.get(URL,verify=False) # request to get the data
     soup_data = bs(scraped_data.text, 'lxml') #parse the scraped data using lxml
     extracted_data = soup_data.find('div',{'id':'pagi_content'}) 
     return extracted_data
```

Then use it to create a dataframe

```
  extract_data = scrap_bid_data(page_no)
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.DataFrame(extract_data)
```

and then export this fataframe.

```
 df.to_csv ('file_name_{}'.format(page_no))
```

Comment: how will predefined header be Inserted ?

Comment: a header can be defined by specifying the name of each column of your dataframe.for example if you only have two columns you can specify their name like this: pd.columns = ["column_1", "column_2"]. Once you do .pd.to_csv () to save your dataframe the header will be present in the csv

Comment: i want bid_data[0], bid_data[5], bid_data[6], bid_data[8] not extract_data  to be exported.

Comment: it's hard for me to know exactly what to do as i can't see your data. Nevertheless after each scraping there is always a part of reorganizing the data before saving them in memory. To do this, you must succeed in extracting the part that interests you and save it in the format that interests you. I advise you to do this to use pandas which is certainly the most intuitive library to start python.